# How to export a calendar from Gnome Calendar to a file?

Tags: 18.10, calendar

I have a version 3.30.0-1 of the Gnome Calendar. I would like to try some other calendar application and therefore I would like to export a calendar to ics file of something appropriate that could be imported in that other application.

Is there a way to export a calendar? Or is there some other way to solve this task?

Answer (score 2):

I have recenty migrated to Ubuntu and as part of the migration process I have done lots of research including looking into calendar apps for Ubuntu and I found that the Gnome Calendar currently does not support exporting calendars, incidentally I found this feature has been requested and consequently filed as a bug/feature request at gitlab a year ago, however it has not entered into the design stages yet, so doesnt look like it will happen anytime soon, you can see the request at:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/issues/31

Having said that, although you currently cannot export Gnome Calendars or events you can however sync with online calendars as shown below:

[Sync Gnome Calendar in Calendar Settings with other Online Account Calendars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVSAU.png)

The following blog demonstrates how this is done:

https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/gnome-caldav

There is also a list of alternatives to GNOME Calendar you may find useful at:

https://alternativeto.net/software/gnome-calendar/

I personally am going to use the Lightning Calendar as it can be integrated into thunderbird and you can synchronize Thunderbird Calendar (Events & Tasks) with Gnome-Shell Built-in Calendar via Evolution or other online Calendars like Google Calendar, Lightning also allows you to export Calendars or Events to HTML, iCalendar or CSV formats. The following link shows you how you can sync lightning with Google Calendar:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar

I just read the other posts and from what Owain said, I could find no Save As option in Gnome calendar to Export the ics file. however, if you look at the paths to the calendar.ics file(s), it appears that Gnome Calendar is in fact evolution under the hood and psw1747 is also right except for the path or at least it seems that way on my system, because I found 3 calendar.ics files, that were there from install, so I thought there must be one ics file for each calendar, which on my system are:

-Birthdays & Anniversaries

-My Calendar

-Personal

and so I added an event to all 3 calendars to determine which file corresponds to which calendar and found that unless something went wrong with the install, all events from all calendars are written only to the one ics file is stored in:

/home/me/.local/share/evolution/calendar/9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1

the other ics files were left untouched including the one in the location that psw1747 posted:

/home/me/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system

/home/me/.local/share/evolution/calendar/trash/9bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf2

**FINAL ANSWER**

In any case it shows that all 3 posts have contributed to the final answer which is that Gnome Calendar is in fact evolution under the hood (Owain) and is stored as an ICS file as psw1747 pointed out , so this explains why there are no import/export calendar options required in the UI, since to import you just need to replace the ICS file you want to import and to export you just locate the ics file import it into your target calendar.
The only problem I can envisage is where you want to import a calendar, but want to preserve the events in your Gnome calendar so you would really need to find a way to merge the two calendars together.

Comment: On my system I can import by clicking calendar file in file manager, Calendar app asks for import then. My calendar location is `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same as Gnome Evolution Mail and Calendar,

"To export a complete calendar, right-click on the calendar in the list of calendars and click Save as. Available formats are iCalendar format (ICS, recommended), comma separated values (CSV), and RDF format.

If you want to export only one appointment (or task or memo), either select the appointment and select File ▸ Save as iCalendar…, or right-click on the appointment and click Save as iCalendar…."

https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exporting-data-calendar.html.en

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think it is the same calendar application https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar